# Doctrine fails to connect to MYSQL database in linked docker container

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using two Docker container, one having ubuntu and an apache webserver running, the other one a mysql server. The containers are linked and i can connect from the ubuntu container onto the mysql server. For the connection I use in the ubuntu container:

```
mysql -u root -h mysql
```

where the second 'mysql' is the name of the container. I can connect to it through the container id as well, so the connection works as well as connecting onto the database from the windows environment.

What doesnt work is the connection from doctrine to the database within the PHP application which is in the ubuntu container.

The config looks like this:

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params'      => array(
                    'host'     => 'mysql',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'db_name',
                    'charset'  => 'utf8',
                )
            )
        ),
)
```

But I get the Error message

```
Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php
```

and

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An abstract factory could not create an instance of doctrine.entitymanager.ormdefault(alias: doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default). in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this and where exactly the error comes from?

I have already tried to put in the container ID as 'host' and commented out the 'password' field as it is not used.

Thanks in advance

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

You need to have pdo_mysql allowed on your system, it doesn't seem a connectivity issue but a php configuration problem.

Can you try to do this command inside your php container

```
php -i | grep pdo_mysql
```

Just to understand if php has this module

Comment: I used the command in the /var/www directory but it didnt give me any output unfortunately :/